# Local Time from geolocation and system time in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-boot

Is it possible, in Java, to obtain the Local time of a geolocation ( Latitude + Longitude ) without asking it to any external server but just calculating it internally to the system, knowing of course where the server is located and its actual time?

can you please provide an implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible. You should somehow find out in what TZ is that particular geolocation.

Comment: It there not a map or library from them i could get those info?